# How to make the simplest minimal huggingface tokenizer?

Tags: pytest, tokenize, huggingface

I would like to make the simplest possible huggingface tokenizer for unit testing code logic. It doesnt have to work well, just produce an output similar to any other tokenizer.

Reading the [course on building a tokenizer](https://huggingface.co/learn/nlp-course/chapter6/8?fw=pt) it seems I could do the following

```py
import tokenizers
tokenizer = tokenizers.Tokenizer(tokenizers.models.WordPiece(unk_token="[UNK]"))
```

But if I try to use it, I get a exception

```py
>>> tokenizer.encode("this is a test text")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: WordPiece error: Missing [UNK] token from the vocabulary
```

The goal is to use the tokenizer in a `pytest` session, so I want it to be lightweight and not download anything pretrained.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it seems you need to do the following:

1. define the unknown token
2. define the vocabulary

```py
>>> import tokenizers
>>> unk_token = "[UNK]"
>>> vocabulary = {unk_token: 0}
>>> tokenizer = tokenizers.Tokenizer(tokenizers.models.WordPiece(vocabulary, >>> unk_token=unk_token))
>>> tokenizer.encode("this is a test text")
Encoding(num_tokens=1, attributes=[ids, type_ids, tokens, offsets, attention_mask, special_tokens_mask, overflowing])
```

The previous example doesnt really split up the string input (`num_tokens=1`)

Therefore optionally, to be more "realistic", you can define a `pre_tokenizer` which just splits on whitespace.

```py
>>> tokenizer.pre_tokenizer = tokenizers.pre_tokenizers.WhitespaceSplit()
>>> tokenizer.encode("this is a test text")
Encoding(num_tokens=5, attributes=[ids, type_ids, tokens, offsets, attention_mask, special_tokens_mask, overflowing])
```

We can observe that all tokens are in fact the `unk_token` which is `0` by looking at the ids.

```py
>>> enc = tokenizer.encode("this is a test text")
>>> enc.ids
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```